# Function that needs to tick

Tags: javascript, increment

So I have this function that adds 3 to a value every second, At the moment it ticks 3 at a time and i want it to tick as 1,2,3 instead of 0-3-6 and so on. As you can see the if statement only gives me gold if the modulo answer is 0. So right now sometimes the value skips every ten number. Thanks for the help!

```
function incrementSecond(){
    amount +=3;
    timesClicked.innerHTML = amount;
    if (amount % 10 === 0) {
        gold++;
        gold.innerHTML = gold;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Does replacing `amount +=3;` with `amount +=1;` do what you want?

Comment: so you want each second to add 1. Then when you reach three you count a gold and reset to 0 and start again?

Comment: please add the interval time.

Comment: No, I want to add 3 each second, and right now I do. But my problem is that by adding 3 each second sometimes my if statement does not return true. My interval time does not matter here. This is only the function which i later call in a interval function.

Comment: if you add 3 each second you will never get 10. You have to rewrite your if statement to get a gold each n seconds and not each 10

Comment: In case you want to increase gold whenever amount increases by ten, you don't actually need extra logic, just do: `gold.innerHTML = Math.floor(amount / 10);`

Answer (score 1):

You could change the iteration time to `1000 / 3`, because you want to add `3` per second.

With a change of the interval time to a third of the original time, you could add one.

```js
function fn() {
    amount++;
    amountElement.innerHTML = amount;
    if (amount % 10 === 0) {
        gold++;
        goldElement.innerHTML = gold;
    }
}

var amount = 0,
    gold = 0,
    amountElement = document.getElementById('amountElement'),
    goldElement = document.getElementById('goldElement');
    
setInterval(fn, 1000 / 3);
```

```html
amount: <span id="amountElement"></span><br>
gold: <span id="goldElement">0</span>
```